# Export-PfxCertificate with foreach scenario

Tags: powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

i'm facing some problems while trying to export the certs from windows stores to .pfx format

The following command works fine ,

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\**** | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "D:\a.pfx" -Password $securestring
```

whereas this doesn't

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? {$_.friendlyname -like "zxy*" }  | sort -Property FriendlyName | % { Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "D:\$($_.friendlyname).pfx" -Password $securestring }
```

Error: Export-PfxCertificate : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

even this doesn't

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\*********** | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "D:\a.pfx" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $_.FriendlyName -Force -AsPlainText)
```

Error:
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.

Please shed some light on it.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: When using the asterisk as a wildcard one is sufficient. ,The 2nd example needs an input, The 3rd has to have a script block around the -Password {} not parentheses ().

Comment: Thanks @LotPings i'd used if for masking the thumbprint, using {} also didnt work. Bender's answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing a certificate to `Export-PfxCertificate` in the second command, you are piping the found certificates to your `ForEach-Object` clause, but aren't making use of the `$PSItem` inside of the block. You have two options:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? {$_.friendlyname -like "zxy*" }  | sort -Property FriendlyName | % { $_ | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "D:\$($_.friendlyname).pfx" -Password $securestring }
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? {$_.friendlyname -like "zxy*" }  | sort -Property FriendlyName | % { Export-PfxCertificate -Certificate $_ -FilePath "D:\$($_.friendlyname).pfx" -Password $securestring }
```

The first one pipes the certificate object for that iteration to `Export-PfxCertificate`, while the second one provides the certificate as a direct argument.

## Why your third attempt didn't work

First thing I see is you're piping `Get-ChildItem` to `Export-PfxCertificate`, which does not take more than a single cert as an argument. If `gci` returns more than one cert, it'll blow up.

Second, you are trying to use the certificate friendly name as the cert password. Not sure if that's your intent, but the code is erroring out because you're trying to use a `$PSItem` out of context, and the returned value winds up being `$null` for a required argument - you need to be in a `ForEach-Object` or `Where-Object` script block to use `$PSItem` or its alias, `$_`. It would work if you did this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\*********** | ForEach-Object { $_ | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath "D:\a.pfx" -Password ( ConvertTo-SecureString -String $_.FriendlyName -Force -AsPlainText ) }
```

Notice that I wrapped the second half of the command in a `ForEach-Object` loop - this solves both problems, only piping one certificate in at a time, and you are also able to access the `FriendlyName` property because that is the currently iterable item, which should be a certificate in this case.

Comment: Thanks Bender, it worked. But i didnt quite understand how its working, could you please point any reference here ?

Comment: Also, for my third command, i'm passing the cert to export command, why isnt that working?